# Extension of continuous functions to the Stone Čech compactification

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a completely regular space. How can I show that every bounded continuous complex function defined on $X$ has a unique extension to a bounded continuous complex function defined on  $\beta(X)$, stone-čech compactification of $X$.

Comment: How are you defining the SC compactification?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded and continuous function. In particular $f(X)\subseteq K$ for some compact subset $K\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, e.g. $K=\overline{f(X)}$. Thus we can consider the corestriction $f':X\to K$, $f'(x)=f(x)$. By the universal property of Stone-Čech compactification $f'$ can be extended to $F:\beta X\to K$ which then composed with the inclusion $i:K\to\mathbb{C}$ gives us an extension of $f$. Of course $F$ is bounded as a continous map defined on a compact space.

Note that any extension to $\beta X$ has to be unique if it exists. That's because $X$ embeds as a dense subspace of $\beta X$ if it is completely regular.

Finally note that the only special thing about $\mathbb{C}$ here is that a bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is contained in some compact subset. The above can be generalized to any continuous function $X\to Y$ with relatively compact image.